# Can MySQL remove rows from results based on whether a column value changes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My goal is to create a dataset output that can be easily charted for easy human readability to discover trends.

Data from `SELECT *` comes out with a string key with the second column in the format:

> [{timestamp: 2022-06-11 08:14:29.111-04:00, value: 5},
> {timestamp: 2022-06-11 08:34:29.111-04:00, value: 5},
> {timestamp: 2022-06-11 09:18:39.111-04:00, value: 3}]

The number of objects in that array will grow over time, and the values need to be tracked, but often will contain duplicate values as this functions as a tracking table for data backup purposes.

My goal is to end up in a format that can be easily read by humans to see changes over time such as:

Key value | timestamp-the-value-changed | value

or

Key Value | timestamp-the-value-first-appeared | last-timestamp-this-value-existed | value

Some of this can be done in Javascript if needed, but that part I can handle easier. Can anyone tell me how close I can get to this output without making the MySQL query too complex?

I have already come closer by flattening the dataset using a cross join on the JSON column, but that doesn't aid with the de-duplication.

As a workable example, the data I describe from the cross-join for the original example appears as:

| Key | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "StringKey1" | 2022-06-11 08:14:29.111-04:00 | 5 |
| "StringKey1" | 2022-06-11 08:34:29.111-04:00 | 5 |
| "StringKey1" | 2022-06-11 09:18:39.111-04:00 | 3 |

Comment: Provide complete output for `SELECT VERSION();`. Provide a sample (CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, 5-7-10 rows, code-formatted textual) with desired output for this data.

Comment: *timestamp: 2022-06-11 08:14:29.111-04:00* - this is not the value which is stored and/or retrieved from MySQL. This is the value interpretation made by your external client or program.